# How to check for URL redirects in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I have been trying to run some URL redirect testing using Google Apps Script in Google Sheets, I've been successful by getting a response code and also the final redirect URL for some of them but most of the links are not working.

Examples of the links I would like to check:

https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/4606613

https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/4661522

https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/6014647

https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/14452305

https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/15910617

Pretty much I need to check if those links will redirect to https://www.airbnb.com/s/homes

Using the script below, I get the following list, which is not correct since all of them will redirect to https://www.airbnb.com/s/homes:

https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/4606613

https://www.airbnb.com/s/homes

https://www.airbnb.com/s/homes

https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/14452305

https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/15910617

It seems that the website is taking 1 second to do the redirect and probably that could be the issue.

Below the code:

```
function urlProtocol(url){
  return URI(url).protocol()
}

function urlHostname(url){
  return URI(url).hostname()
}

function getRedirects(url) {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://rawgit.com/medialize/URI.js/gh-pages/src/URI.js').getContentText());

  var params = {
    'followRedirects': false,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  var baseUrl = urlProtocol(url) + "://" + urlHostname(url),
      response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params),
      responseCode = response.getResponseCode();

  if(response.getHeaders()['Location']){
    var redirectedUrl = getRedirects(baseUrl + response.getHeaders()['Location']);
    return redirectedUrl;
  } else {
    return url;
  }
}
```

Comment: On the code, the followRedirects method is set to false, is it different from the FetchApp? Since I believe the parameters are correlated to the eval

Comment: Well, I obviously did not read the code in your question, sorry about previous comment (already realized that and removed). One thing is still valid, though - I would check the response code first to be 3xx, then check the header and only then recurse.

Comment: As it stands now, your logic seems fine to me. Can you please add an example of a URL that is not set to redirect to /home?

Comment: One extra thing - I would not reevaluate the URL external library each time you need to call `getRadirects` - one time is enough, since it basically an import. You can move it global scope and change `eval` to `Function()` constructor (you never know what's on the other side after all)

Comment: @OlegValter an example URL is  https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/23861670 ,  when running the code I get no redirect but so the same with most of them.

Comment: Thanks - you know what, I checked myself, and the issue is probably with airbnb. Some links inconsistently lead to redirect. For example, room `15910617` sometimes redirects to home and sometimes loads the room required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the final redirect on some of the URLs happens *after* the page is loaded. Most likely there is a client-side script that initiates the change of `window.location`. Therefore, your correct logic fails to catch such pages.

To make matters worse, after-load redirect seem to be inconsistent as sometimes the pages you provided are not redirected to `https://www.airbnb.com/s/homes`. I was able to stop this redirect from happening, so the theory is confirmed - will update with what exactly causes it.

---

Apart from that, there are several optimizations you can apply to your script:

1. Get rid of `eval` and, actually, of the whole library unless you really need it (see how to do the same in just two lines). Improved security is the main benefit: no `eval()` of external scripts means less possibilities for breach.
2. Check for status code in 3xx range before looking through the `Location` header (as a precaucion).

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {string} target 
 */
const getRedirects = (target) =>

  /**
   * @param {string}
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  (url) => {

    if(url === target) {
      return false;
    }

    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      'followRedirects': false,
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
    });

    const code = response.getResponseCode();

    let { Location } = response.getHeaders();

    if (code < 300 || code >= 400) {
      return true;
    }

    if (!Location) {
      return false;
    }

    if (/^\/\w+/.test(Location)) {
      const [protocol, , base] = url.split("/");
      Location = `${protocol}//${base}${Location}`;
    }

    console.log(Location);
    
    return getRedirects(target)(Location);
  };

const testRedirects = () => {

  const redirectsToHome = getRedirects("https://www.airbnb.com/s/homes");

  const accessible = [
    "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/23861670",
    "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/4606613",
    "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/4661522",
    "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/6014647",
    "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/14452305",
    "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/15910617"
  ].filter(redirectsToHome);

  console.log(accessible);
};
```

Since the clarification that the function is a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function), you can add a wrapper function that will serve as public API that you can reference in a cell that will call the utility, something like this:

```
const checkIfRedirects = (source, target = "https://www.airbnb.com/s/homes") => getRedirects(target)(source);
```

You can then use it like you would do a formula:

```
=checkIfRedirects(A20)
```

Comment: Since I will be running this out of cell values, should I use it like a UDF (=getRedirects(A2)) ? I'm not quite getting the filter method statement

Comment: Oh, I did not get you wanted to use a custom function - I used an areay and filter for demonstration mostly. If used as CF, it should be redesigned a bit

Comment: Either a custom function or just running the script, my question is how should I run this, and how can I retrieve a list of Urls in cells, an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HFcc7GeuGTX2F-G5wYQVuXylp1XiCykAB2Uf5-QeMPU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Excelsson - well, instead of a boolean value (I used it for utility to be a general-purpose one) you can return the `url` instead of `true` when the fetch is successful and an empty string (or whatever you want to be returned in that case) instead of `false`. As for how to call in a cell - see the update, in a script - as you want a list of values I would use it paired with `map` method